# How to find the cause of 'The following module has moved within the system'?

Tags: 7

I can't get rid of this message whenever I install a module, it shows:

> User warning: The following module has moved within the file system: [modulename]. In order to fix this, clear caches or put the module back in its original location. For more information, see the documentation page. in _drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1138 of /data/all/000/core/drupal-7.54.2/includes/bootstrap.inc).

I read the documentation mentioned, but cannot find a module that could cause this.

What would be the right way to find the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be tough to find the module that causes your error message.

However, you may want to have a look at '[How to fix "The following module is missing from the file system..." warning messages](https://www.drupal.org/node/2487215)' which describes a few possible causes and corresponding solutions, such as:

- You removed a module from the file system without disabling and uninstalling it.
- You moved the module inside your Drupal installation.
- Leftover fields or other configuration entries.
- Obsolete modules existed from a previous Drupal version.
- There is a bug in a module installed on your site.

The one I ever used in the past (to get rid of that message) is to use the module '[Module Missing Message Fixer](https://www.drupal.org/project/module_missing_message_fixer)' (also mentioned on that same page).

Comment: The OP stated it happens when he "installs" the module. And I've got this happening too on modules which do not meet any of those conditions.

Comment: @Adaddinsane the items (bullets) I mentioned are preceeded by "... such as". That is: this is an incomplete list. I suggest you have a look at the linked page, to verify if it could be any of the reasons mentioned near the end of it (before the comments start). If you do find another reason / cause (apart from those I mentioned), please add another answer (something like "another cause is ..."). OK?